# make a select in a select statement mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

Maybe my title is very vague. since I dont know how what im looking for is called.

So here is my problem.

since my navigator on my website is create with two table. like the following.

```
MainCategory
 -id
 -name
Category
 -id
 -name
 -maincategory
 -sub
```

Of course the complexity of those two table is more than that but this is the esential for my problem.

So. im trying to create a new nav that could load faster ( hopefully I can get the content of the nav with only one one mysql call )

every category has an maincategory field that is the id that point to the corect MainCategory, Sometime a category is a subCategory of an category.

So im trying to have a row for every category every if it a sub or a simple category

this is my mysql query.

```
SELECT category.id AS id, category.name AS catName, maincategory.name AS mainCatName,     maincategory.id AS mainCatId, (
category.sub = category.id
) AS catSubName
FROM category
INNER JOIN maincategory ON ( category.maincategory = maincategory.id )
```

But in the field catSubName i need the name of the category.id

With the query that i tryed to put togther I have this output
[image]

What I would like tho is the same output but that in the field catSubName to have the categoryname instead.   Right now I only have 0 for all category.

Let say that the catName "`Cleaning Supplies`"(742) is a subCategory of "`Others`"(743)
then in the field "`catSubName`" of "`id`" 742 i would like to have the string "Other" of the catName 743

the conent of `catSubName` should be category.name of the category.sub that is equal of the category.id that the category.name is in.. :S

I hope this is clearing up the confusing question a little. :S

Thanks for any input!

Comment: very confusing, please give some input/output examples

Comment: Sorry, Il try to update my question to be clear as most as possible

Comment: I updated the end of my question with an example of what id like to get from my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your comment suggests category is a recursive hierarchy, where `sub` refers to the `id` of the sub category within the same table, you should use:

```
SELECT c.id AS id,
       c.name AS catName,
       m.name AS mainCatName,
       m.id AS mainCatId,
       s.name AS catSubName
FROM category c
     INNER JOIN maincategory m ON ( c.maincategory = m.id ) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN category s ON (c.sub = s.id)
```

I used an outer join here - which delivers results even if the category has no sub category. But I am no sure how your database design is, hence this may need adaptation.

Comment: Im going to try this query, but i can't see how this is going to do the job for me since from my understanding category.sub will select the current row sub and this field is an id and not the string name of the pointing id

Comment: @NicolasRacine Where then can you find the name you are interested in?

Comment: The Name I need is at category.name of category.sub = category.id

Comment: @NicolasRacine Ok, I understand: There is a recursion within `category`. I did not read that from your question. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: !!! THANKS i had to edit your query a litle tho,   `s.sub AS catSubName` to `s.name AS catSubName`  Thanks Any how!

Comment: That is no worry, Thanks to took the time to twist your brain for me! I was really lost there..